# SSMS behaves strangely when I try to open list of tables

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SSMS 11.0.6020.0, labeled as SSMS 2012 to connect SQL Server. If I click New Query and run

```
use MyDatabase;
```

the response is

> Command(s) completed successfully.

But if I try to open the tables folder of the Object Explorer, the response is, as of today, the following:

[image: Error Dialog]

What could be the cause of this behavior?

EDIT:

I have realized that I had an unfinished transaction in SSMS and when I closed SSMS, the transaction was cancelled. If I run an unfinished transaction in SSMS, then it is unable to open the tables, at least this is what I empyrically observed. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Comment: i thing the common cause is a transaction which is rolling back in your server. You can resolve this by restart the server

Comment: @bmsqldev, I was able to work around the problem by restarting SSMS, the server did not need to be restarted.

Comment: Actually I mentioned sql-server only. somehow sql missed from it :).

Comment: @bmsqldev, again, there was no need to restart the server. I have restarted SSMS only, SQL Server was not restarted.